# iterate through dict keys, pass into new dict, if keys don't exist, pass key with a value of None

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, iterator

Edit: This is what i came up with to produce the desired results based on the answers given. i'll wrap it in a function. sure its not the most efficent but works :)

```
for k in required_fields:
if k in response_data.keys():
    print(k, response_data[k])
else:
    print(k, None)
```

I'm new to programming (couple weeks), this is my first project.

I'm collecting timeseries data from ByBit exchange websocket, converting from JSON into Dict and storing it into a database. The websocket only sends updated data, so one or more of the converted Dict keys can be absent. I can't figure out how to account for this without throwing KeyError. I've tried using .get() but it only supports a single argument and i'm not sure how to use it in an iterable to create a new dict.

Ultimately i'd like to commit the desired key values into postgres, passing Value as 'None' if they're nonexistent OR not passing them at all and leaving the table column blank. I'n my inexperience i'm not sure which is preferable.

This is a sample of the message after I've converted to Dict, the nested dictionary 'data' is the one that can vary. EG if price doesn't change between trade, price will not be in message.

```
response_dict = ({'success': 'True', 'topic': 'trade.EOSUSD', 'data': [{'timestamp': '2019-06-20T10:06:36.030Z', 'symbol': 'EOSUSD', 'side': 'Sell',
                                                                    'size': 757, 'price': 6.77, 'tick_direction': 'PlusTick', 'trade_id': '5658ec5f-90ce-4244-9192-3f29057e223a', 'cross_seq': 59462597}]})
```

EDIT: To clarify, This is an example of another possible message from the same subscription, for example the price hasn't changes so the server isn't sending the price key, values pair.

```
response_dict = ({'success': 'True', 'topic': 'trade.EOSUSD', 'data': [{'timestamp': '2019-06-20T10:06:36.030Z', 'symbol': 'EOSUSD', 'side': 'Sell',
                                                                    'size': 757, 'tick_direction': 'PlusTick', 'trade_id': '5658ec5f-90ce-4244-9192-3f29057e223a', 'cross_seq': 59462597}]})
```

This is the function i'm using to extract the nested dictionary 'data', required_fields are the keys i'd like committed to the database.

```
def response_process(response_input):
    if "topic" in response_input and "trade" in response_input["topic"]:
        response_data = response_input["data"][0]
        required_fields = ['timestamp', 'symbol',
                           'side', 'size', 'price', 'tick_direction']
        response_data_2 = {key: value for key, value in response_data.items(
        ) if key in required_fields}
        updated_timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(
            response_data_2['timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
        response_data_2['timestamp'] = updated_timestamp
        commit_postgres(response_data_2)
```

and here's how im commiting this data into PostGres

```
def commit_postgres(response_data_input):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password = 'postgres123' host='localhost' port= '5432'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {symbol} (timestamp text, side text, size float, price float, tick_direction text)".format(**response_data_input))
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO {symbol}(timestamp, side, size, price, tick_direction) VALUES (%(timestamp)s, %(side)s, %(size)s, %(price)s, %(tick_direction)s)".format(
        **response_data_input), (response_data_input))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the required fields, not the keys of the dictionary in the response. Then use `if/else` when assigning the value in the new dictionary.

```
response_data_2 = {key: (response_data[value] if key in response_data else None) for value in required_fields}
```

Comment: this throws "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)". i assume it's trying unpack the list into a single key? as i said i'm very green to python so just an assumption.

Comment: Fixed the code. It's supposed to get the old value from `response_data`, not `required_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dict.update`:

```py
>>> d = dict(a=23, b=42, c=None)                                                                                                                                                              
>>> d                                                                                                                                                                                         
{'a': 23, 'b': 42, 'c': None}                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> d.update({'a' : 'foobar'})                                                                                                                                                                
>>> d                                                                                                                                                                                         
{'a': 'foobar', 'b': 42, 'c': None}
```

Comment: He only wants to add fields that are missing, not replace existing fields.

Comment: > Ultimately i'd like to commit the desired key values into postgres, passing Value as 'None' if they're nonexistent OR not passing them at all and leaving the table column blank.
The other k/v were for illustration...

Comment: i've edited the first post to show another sample websocket responce message with a missing key,value pair, Sorry if the question comes across a little vague or confusing, very green to python and programming in general :)